# How to get the image url after callback in ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-activestorage

I have a model named Food where i have used active storage to save the image of food.
I have set a **after_create** callback where i want to get the image url. To do this i have done

```
class Food < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image

  after_create :check_image_url
  private
  def check_image_url
    url = url_for self.image
  end
end
```

But this gives me a error
`` undefined method `url_for' for #<Food:0x00007f6b4cd7c440> ``

Is there anyway i can achieve this?

Comment: There are couple of ways. Check a conversation [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31581) to learn more about it.

Comment: You want to use `self.url =` if you want this code to do anything except assign a local variable thats garbage collected instantly.